# Hyperledger Fabric Failed to Instantiate chaincode unsupported protocol scheme "tcp"

Tags: tcp, config, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, peer

I'm trying to start a hyperledger fabric 1.2.0 network spread over 2 ubuntu VM's (one orderer and peer) and my own computer to invoke the cli commands. So far I've started the orderer and peer machines, updated anchor peer for the peer machine, and installed the chaincode.

However, upon instantiating the chaincode with the chaincode isntantiate command, I receive an error that says `unsupported protocol scheme "tcp"`.

I successfully installed the chaincode with the following command:

```
 peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p chaincode_example02/
```

The command I used to instantiate the chaincode is:

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o 192.168.0.150:7050 --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/0.150/orderers/192.168.0.150/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.0.150-cert.pem -C myownnetworkchannel -n mycc -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a", "100", "b","200"]}' -P "AND ('Org1MSP.peer')"
```

The error message that I got on the client cli is:

```
Error: could not assemble transaction, err Proposal response was not 
successful, error code 500, msg failed to execute transaction 
4b31df457c0c5642f98689e6887db4fefa79a8547b182ee481f7ff03320c02f9: error 
starting container: error starting container: Post 
tcp:///var/run/docker.sock/containers/create?name=dev-peer0.0.155-mycc- 
1.0: unsupported protocol scheme "tcp"
```

**Additional Peer logs**

```
2018-09-18 22:38:15.448 EDT [chaincode] Launch -> ERRO bf0b start failed: Post tcp:///var/run/docker.sock/containers/create?name=dev-peer0.0.155-mycc-1.0: unsupported 
protocol scheme "tcp"
error starting container
error starting container
2018-09-18 22:38:15.448 EDT [endorser] callChaincode -> DEBU bf0c [myownnetworkchannel][3ed01a8ccc3fff617c04d7307811c4f777f6b81588b21d7c549e4bcd300949f6] Exit
2018-09-18 22:38:15.449 EDT [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO bf0d [myownnetworkchannel][3ed01a8c] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: Post tcp:///var/ru
n/docker.sock/containers/create?name=dev-peer0.0.155-mycc-1.0: unsupported protocol scheme "tcp"
error starting container
error starting container
```

My question is, is the problem caused by my peer machine's `core.yaml` config or from the core config file i used in my computer? I've tried changing the vm `endpoint` (that points to `docker.sock` file) and `addressAutoDetect` configuration in my computer to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there was something I missed within my `core.yaml` config for the Peer machine.

**core.yaml**

```
...
###############################################################################
#
#    VM section
#
###############################################################################
vm:

# Endpoint of the vm management system.  For docker can be one of the following in general
# unix:///var/run/docker.sock
# http://localhost:2375
# https://localhost:2376
endpoint: /var/run/docker.sock #incorrect config causing the tcp issue
endpoint: unix:///var/run/docker.sock #correct config
```

After searching around for a solution I came across this [docker.sock stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110146/can-anyone-explain-docker-sock/35110344) that explains how a docker container is exposed through the 'UNIX' socket instead of tcp.