# Is Docker a security threat running on a desktop?

Tags: docker, security

Is Docker a security threat when running on a desktop?

Comment: Anyone who can run any Docker anything has unrestricted root access over your system.  If you've reconfigured Docker to allow network access to its socket, it's especially vulnerable.  If the socket is suitably protected, Docker isn't a special risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted by David Maze, yes, Docker can become security threat when its [socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110146/can-anyone-explain-docker-sock/35110344) is configured with network access. But this does not happen with the default install.

Comment: Did you configure the socket with network access on your desktop? That would not be a normal install.

Comment: No, my install is a default install.

Comment: A default install should not have a security risk. But if you have access to run containers, and someone gains access to run commands as you, then that person can run containers, along with any process outside of a container which would be a more significant security risk.