# Unable to instantiate the chaincode in muticloud setup

Tags: virtual-machine, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to achieve the multicloud architecture. My network has 2 peers, 1 orderer and a webclient. This network is in Azure. I am trying to add a peer from Google Cloud Platform to the channel of Azure. For this, I created a crypto-config for 3rd peer from Azure webclient. But in the crypto-config, I made the changes like peers in Azure have their own certificates while for the 3rd peer, I placed the newly created certificates. Now I can install, instantiate, invoke and do queries in the peers(1 and 2). And I can install the chaincodes in 3rd peer. But I am unable to instantiate the chaincodes.
Getting the following error: Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg error starting container: error starting container: Post http://unix.sock/containers/create?name=dev-(CORE_PEER_ID)-documentCC-1: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
Can anyone guide me on this.

Note: All the peers, orderer, webclient are running in different vm(s)

Answer (score 0):

@soundarya

It doesn’t matter how many places your solution is deployed

The problem is you are running docker by using sudo command try to add docker to sudo group 
Below block will help you out

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socket

To learn more concept about docker.sock 
You can refer to my answer in another [Can anyone explain docker.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110146/can-anyone-explain-docker-sock)