# What is the result of mounting `/var/run/docker.sock` in a Docker in Docker scenario?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, unix-socket, docker-in-docker

I've read [Can anyone explain docker.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110146/can-anyone-explain-docker-sock/35110344) to understand what `/var/run/docker.sock` does, but its use in GitLab CI's [Use Docker socket binding](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-socket-binding) has me confused.

Here is their example command for the `gitlab-runner` registration:

```bash
sudo gitlab-runner register -n \
  --url https://gitlab.com/ \
  --registration-token REGISTRATION_TOKEN \
  --executor docker \
  --description "My Docker Runner" \
  --docker-image "docker:19.03.12" \
  --docker-volumes /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

I see two places that the resulting container could obtain `docker` from.

1. The unix socket `/var/run/docker.sock`.
2. The `docker` binary included in the base image `docker:19.03.12`.

Isn't this a `PATH` conflict? I thought it should be one or the other, where I obtain the ability to use `docker` from either the host's unix socket or the base image.

I would think that `--docker-image` should instead be `ubuntu:latest` or something along those lines that doesn't come with `docker`, since the `PATH`'s `docker` would already come from the host socket. Alternatively, the docker socket mount would be removed.

What is actually happening here in regards to this double inclusion of `docker`?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/

Comment: @DucNguyen Yup that helped me learned about `/var/run/docker.sock`, but `gitlab-runner` is mounting the docker socket on top of a docker in docker image, not as an alternative like described in your link. That's what the question is about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Unix socket file `/var/run/docker.sock` is normally created by the Docker daemon.  If you run something else as the main container process, the socket won't get created.  You can directly look by running a container with a non-Docker main process, like `/bin/ls`:

```
docker run --rm docker:19.03.12 ls -l /var/run
docker run --rm docker:19.03.12 ls -l /run
```

The `/usr/bin/docker` binary must exist in the container filesystem, if you're going to use it.  Containers can never call binaries that are on the host, and the socket API won't produce a binary either.  (Some of the very early "use the host's Docker socket" posts advocated bind-mounting the binary into the container, but this leads to trouble with library dependencies and makes images not be self-contained.)

So if all you actually need is a Docker container, with a `docker` binary, that can invoke the host's Docker socket, you need an image like [`docker`](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) where the *image* has a `/usr/bin/docker`, plus you need to bind-mount the host's `/var/run/docker.sock` into the container.

```
docker run \
  --rm \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  docker:19.03.12 \
  docker ps
```

---

The GitLab setup you link to seems rather contrived.  Using the `docker` image to run jobs means that pretty much the *only* thing a build step can run is a `docker` command.  At a technical level, you can't start the `docker` container without already having a `docker` binary and access to a running Docker daemon; the shell-executor approach described at the top of that page seems simpler and there aren't really any downsides to it.

You also also might find it convenient to have a Docker image of build-time dependencies (compilers, header files, static checking tools, ...).  That would let you update these dependencies without having to roll out an update to your entire build cluster.  If your build scripts themselves need to invoke `docker` then your build-tools image needs to install Docker, just using a normal `RUN apt-get install` command.  You need to push the host's Docker socket into the container in the same way, and so you don't need to start a separate Docker daemon.

Comment: (I don't think the setup you're describing is "Docker-in-Docker".  I'm used to that term meaning "run a Docker daemon inside a container", and not "run a `docker` binary in a container accessing the host's Docker daemon".  The page you link to describes a Docker-in-Docker setup, immediately above the specific anchor you mention.)

Comment: Great answer. If I run `docker run --rm docker:19.03.12 docker ps` (so without the socket mount), there's an error about the docker TCP lookup failing. I thought that because `docker ps` is the main process here (instead of something like `ls`), the socket would get created and that docker lookup would resolve to an internally created socket. What am I missing here?

Comment: And about the last paragraph, if I install `docker` with the `apt-get install`, I wouldn't have to inherit from a base `docker:*` image right? I would just do the socket mount and the `apt-get install`?

Comment: If you `docker run docker docker ps`, the only process that runs in the container is the Docker client binary; it won't automatically start a daemon.  (In the same way `docker run nginx sh` runs an interactive shell _instead of_ the Nginx server.)

Comment: And yes, if you have a Debian-based image and `RUN apt-get install docker.io`, that puts a `/usr/bin/docker` binary into your image and you don't specifically need to extend the `docker` image, but you need to bind-mount the Docker socket when you run the container.

Comment: When I mount docker.sock file, ls -l shows nobody nogroup and I can't run docker inside container(permission denied). On the host machine, my user is inside docker group, but not sudo. Privileged, userns, chown docker.sock inside the container, changing docker group id inside the container as the host machine; both of them did not work. Do you have any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to understand how docker works in order to understand this flow the docker has a server and a client `docker-cli` and `docker daemon`  the client communicate with the docker daemon using `APIS`.

the `docker.sock` is the UNIX socket that ensure connection between a the docker client and the daemon (server).

Since docker container unlike Virtual machine don't have a `kernel` each container run in docker uses the host's kernel and build the container in top of the host's kernel.
a container doesn't have a kernel itself so you can't build a docker inside a docker unless you use the host's kernel.

the gitlab-runner has many exectors :  `shell` `ssh`  `docker`  etc ...

using the docker executer means the runner will  create a container and than clone you repo inside this container and run the scripts you pass and then destroys this container.

the gitlan-runner needs a base image in order to create the container that will run the scripts. you don't have to use `docker:19.03.12` or mount `/var/run/docker.sock` volume  unless your script  has docker commands (or in general you need to have access to the docker ) and both of the strategies are differents  you should know that mounting the `docker.sock` is not a docker in docker.

in order to achieve docker in docker you need to add  `--privileged` flag to a container which basically makes root in your container be full root on the host. it can manage kernel params, it has all capabilities .

here's a good [reference](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/) on this subject