# How to configure permissions for the VSCode terminal?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I recently installed docker on my Ubuntu 20.04 PC. I had to grant myself the permission to use it by adding myself to the `docker` group like so: `sudo usermod -aG docker tom`.

However, when I open a terminal in VSCode, I does not show `tom` as the user, but some random string like `user@64a57a936f8d`. I believe this is why I can't execute docker commands or use the docker extension in VSCode.

So how do I manage the permissions for this VSCode-"user"?

Comment: are you running vscode inside of the container?

Comment: if that is the case - you need to tell that container where to find the docker daemon

Comment: @Daniel that could be the case, I just pulled the project off github and used the standard settings. How can I tell the container where the daemon is?

Comment: which project? how'd you setup vscode? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110146/can-anyone-explain-docker-sock/35110344

Comment: @Daniel [This one](https://github.com/PX4/PX4-Autopilot). I just have a standard installation of VSCode - The project included lots of addons, one of them was [the docker extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-docker).